# inline generic delegate (not the normal Action<T> Func<T, TResult>)

Tags: c#, delegates, generics

Is it possible to write an inline generic method? For example, how can I translate the below method into an inline delegate.

```
public TUser Current<TUser>() where TUser : User
{
     return getCurrentUser() as TUser;
}
```

Even just being able to call

```
Func<User> userFunc = new Func<User>(Current<User>);
```

would be useful.

Comment: That does not make any sense. How would you want to use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression in C# 3.0:

```
Func<User> userFunc = () => getCurrentUser() as User;
```

or

```
Func<User> userFunc = Current<User>;
```

Comment: Since the method Current<User> already have a matching type you should be able to simply write 'Func<User> userFunc = Current<User>;'